# Figma's "After Delay" interaction is disabled when going from one frame to another

Tags: prototyping, figma

Working on a loading indicator animation; when I tap on prototype, I want the transition to happen from one frame to another after an "After Delay" interaction. As you can see in the photo, "After Delay" is disabled, hovering over it does not give me any explanation. What's going on?

The goal here is to have a loading indicator prototy

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the frame instead, then try prototyping (you have only the object selected).
if you select the complete frame it's gonna enable it, and it's disabled when an object is selected.

Comment: Yep, this is correct, you must select the frame. Wish they had some tooltip explaining this so I wouldn't get stuck like this.

Comment: @Zorayr Agreed on the tooltip